# Change text woocommerce minicart buttons

Tags: php, function, woocommerce

On our Staging-Site for ergotopia.de I am trying to change the button text of the dropdown minicart, like you see in picture. To reduce confusing: On ergotopia.de its the right text, but since updates (which we test on our Staging) it was changing the buttons text, and I am unable to change the text.

[image]

**I tried the following things, without success:**

1. translations via loco-translate
2. functions.php with following code:

   `add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text');
   add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');`

   `function translate_text($translated) {
   $translated = str_ireplace('Kasse', 'Weiter zur Kasse', $translated);
   return $translated;
   }`
3. In Child Theme (childtheme\woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php)  I edited the file in line 1487:

   `function woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout() {
       echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ) . '" class="button checkout wc-forward">' . esc_html__( 'Weiter zur Kasse', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
   }`

**Do you know how to change it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** I had to add priority like

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text',999);
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text',999);
```